# Windows 10 - how to open an admin cmd prompt from file explorer address bar?

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe

I learned recently that you can open a command prompt from within file explorer by typing cmd in the address bar. And this will open in the current directory.

How do you open it up from the address bar as an admin?

Comment: You don't. But press Windows key, type "cmd" in Search and press Shift-Ctrl-Enter to get Admin CMD easily.

Answer (score 0):

you have your answer in comment but there is a faster way would be press press windows +x you will see that it would show poweshell but you can change that by going in setting>personalisation>taskbar>Replace cmd with.... Disable itand next time you press windows+ x you will see cmd as admin
Even shoter is prees windows+r  anywhere type cmd hold ctrl +shift and press enter